# How to loadbalance with linux routes

Tags: linux, networking

If I add 50000 rules to routes by "route add **** " command, I want to know, does this make the route slow ?

Actually, I have 50000 rules and these rules are dynamic, I can add/delete some rules at any time. Is this possible to loadbalance ?

Comment: Uhm... is this a real question? 50.000 static routes? Really?..

Comment: How many interface, both real and virtual, does this machine have?

Comment: 2 interface, this machine is a gateway server.

Comment: Are you talking about routes, or firewall rules?

Comment: just routes, i need to forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will make it slow, since BGP4 on linux (using quagga) does the same thing. If you get the global routing table, it inserts all known routes (couple hundred thousand) in the kernel routing table. But unless you are using a routing protocol (BGP, OSPF, etc), why do you have the need for 50k routes in your routing table?

Comment: Thank you! because it's the business thing. that's to say, the target ip i need to forward has no rule.

Comment: And I am not familiar with BGP :(, can you give me a simple description ? thanks again!

Comment: @sharp I suggest you look up BGP on wikipedia.  Here, I'll do it for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bgp

Comment: I still don't understand what the "business thing" is and why you need 50k routes in your routing table?